# Form Post of an Complex Model to Controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have a question regarding a Form Post of an complex Model. My Model has a subclass and `IEnumerable`s:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SingleInteger { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> MultipleInts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MySubclass> AssembledClass { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> MultipleStrings { get; set; }
}

public class MySubclass
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Type{ get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to get the Input from my View to my Controller? Can the Modelbinder even bind this?

Comment: There is no such thing as MVC6 ;)

Comment: If this is a *real* form post, the actual data design of your HTML form is a lot more interesting than this. – But yeah, the model binder won’t be a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the Modelbinder even bind this?

Yes, and it can do a lot more complexed stuff then this class structure.

> What is the best way to get the Input from my View to my Controller?

Post is as json.

**Example:**

You could POST this json

```
{"singleInteger":1,"multipleInts":[1,2,3],"assembledClass":[{"quantity":1,"type":2}],"multipleStrings":["one","two"]}
```

To an controller method like this

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]MyViewModel model)
```

And it will be translated into an instance of MyViewModel like this

```
var model = new MyViewModel
{
    SingleInteger = 1,
    MultipleInts = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 },
    AssembledClass = new List<MySubclass>{
        new MySubclass 
        {
            Quantity = 1,
            Type = 2
        }
    },
    MultipleStrings = new List<string>(){ "one", "two"} 
};
```